# Check that index file exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an index on my table like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_typ_poplatky
    ON Auta (typ DESC, poplatok_denny DESC, poplatok_km DESC);
```

How to I check that the index file exists?

Comment: Where you say "...the index file exists?" do you mean how do you check that the index has been created successfully and can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check when connected as the schema owner:

```
select index_name from user_indexes
where index_name = 'INDEX_TYP_POLATYKY';
```

or

```
select index_name from user_indexes
where table_name = 'AUTA';
```

Note that the index name and table name are stored in uppercase.

You can also select from USER_IND_COLUMNS to find out the columns that are indexed:

```
select column_name
from user_ind_columns
where index_name = 'INDEX_TYP_POLATYKY'
order by column_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[table name]') AND name = N'index name')

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for Oracle.